# Magento V2 - changing attribute set never updates and I see a continuous please wait

Tags: magento2

[image]

Any time I attempt to update the attribute set from default to another attribute set, the product never updates and the settings never save. I get a continuous please wait spinning gif. Also in my dev tools console, I get a JS error as seen below. Any thoughts on what may be going on. This seems to be related to the Magento V2 upgrade done recently. I am not sure if the JS error is related or not but I wanted to at least mention it.

[image]

Comment: Also when I just hit the save button, I get an invalid form key could this be related?

Comment: Even with it now saving it still does not work.